# C# EF Add-migration -Force doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to overwrite the InitialModel Migration because i added a new DbSet under customer DbSet like this :

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }


        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

After I added the Movies DbSet i run

```
add-migration InitialModel -Force
```

To overwrite the IntialModel migration file and create the Movies Table, so that it will appear as createTable in the up method inside InitialModel  migration file like what happend with customers table like this :

```
 public partial class IitialModel : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Customers",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

Every time i tried to run

```
add-migration InitialModel -Force
```

after adding the DbSet 
it creates a new migration file called InitialModel1 it's not what i want, i want to overwrite the InitialModel migration fie to createTable called Movies inside it?

Comment: That really is not the proper technique for migrations. If you are just going to keep overwriting the same migration with every change you might as well use [automatic migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554735(v=vs.113).aspx) or just let an initializer handle it until your model stabilizes. Otherwise just add your migration incrementally and [roll them up](https://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/) at some point if they become too numerous.

Answer (score -3):

please try specifying the name explicitly and add the verbose flag:

```
Add-Migration -Name InitialModel -Verbose -Force
```

Then please show us the detailed log.

Comment: Using StartUp project 'vidly'.
Using NuGet project 'vidly'.
Scaffolding migration 'IitialModel'.
The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration IitialModel' again.
Target database is: 'aspnet-vidly-20170214064956' (DataSource: (LocalDb)\v11.0, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).

Comment: ...just noticed that you have a typo. Your first migration is called IitialModel (without n) but your command is "add-migration InitialModel -Force"  (with a n). Please check your migration names and, eventually, retry.